# How do i create structure to show coordinates that user selects?

Tags: c++, structure

**Hi how do i create structers to store coordinates and turn 'O' to the 'X' from grid when user enters that coordinate?[image of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcNv2.png)**

i started learning c++ just for like 1 week ago and im not very good at putting what's on my mind to real code and this is my first time using this platform so im not good at asking for help either sorry :/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void showMap();
void createMap();


char map[6][6];

int main()
{
 createMap();
 showMap();
 
 

    return 0;}
    
void createMap(){
    
    map[0][0]=' ';
    
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        
        map[0][i]=i+48;
    }
    
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        
        map[i][0]=i+64;
    }
    
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
        
        for(int j=1;j<6;j++){
            map[i][j]='O';
        }
    }
}
void showMap()
{
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            cout << map[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this:  `struct Point {int x; int y;};`.  This can be used to hold the row and column.  So can `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: Since you are doing `using namespace std;`, there already is a symbol `std::map`, which may conflict with your `map` array.  A better idea is: `using std::cout; using std::endl;` Which only brings in 2 out of too many symbols from the `std` namespace.

Comment: Prefer to use a character literal rather than the ASCII decimal encoding.  For example, use `i + '0'`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a location structure:

```
struct Location
{
    unsigned int row;
    unsigned int column;
    void Enter_Location()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter row: ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << "Enter column: ";
        std::cin >> column;
    }
};
```

To assign to your map:

```
Location l;
l.Enter_Location();
map[l.row][l.column] = 'X';
```